# The content-type header value is getting changed while accessing webpage from WebStorm internal server

Tags: configuration, webstorm, content-type, response-headers

When I am trying to access Angular page from WebStorm's internal server, I am getting 404 error for all the js and css files. Only html content is being served but not the resources like css and js files. When I looked at Content-Type request header it is being modified to text/html instead of application/js or text/css.

The X-Content-Type-Options value is set to nosniff. Referrer header is also set to the same ip address from where the html page is being accessed. I am using http not https.

What we observed is when referrer header is not set then the page along with its css and js resources are being accessed.

I think we can set rel attribute only for links but how this can be applied for JS files as there is no rel attribute in script tag.

Comment: <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" /> this line helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: Satya, thanks, this helped me! I logged an issue with jetbrains about it as well; in case others have the same issue I'll link it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28826